# Entity not queried immediately after commit in data nucleus JPA

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus

I am using Data Nucleus JPA for persistence in my GWT application. my persist API in Entity looks like this:

---

EntityManager em = EMF.getEM();

```
try {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    if(!em.contains(this)){
       em.persist(this);
       em.flush();
    }
    em.getTransaction().commit();
} finally {
    em.close();
}
```

---

I am following this document: http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jpa/transactions.html#local

This code works fine and commits data. But when I query the committed record immediately after commit, sometimes entity is not queried. If I query after after few seconds, it is queried. Please note that this issue is intermittent.

Any hints/suggestions what could be the cause of this intermittent issue?

Thanks

Comment: you mean on appengine?

Comment: Yes. I am running it on google app engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you do a Google search for "eventual consistency" and read the GAE docs, since it mentions this concept

Comment: This sounds very much the issue for inconsistent behavior. I will look into it. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This page talks about Strcuturing for Strong consistency and it solved the problem for me. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

Basically including ancestor definition in your query e.g,

Query query = new Query("Entity").setAncestor(ancestorKey).setFilter(filter);